# selecting date for a textbox

Tags: visual-studio-2008, textbox

I want to know how to add date entry to a textbox in a webpage. I am using visual studio 2008. Please let me know how to do it.
I have a textbox for entering the date of birth of an employee and I have to enter values into it from a calendar.

Comment: You will probably have to give more specific information about your problem to get help. E.g. programming language, frameworks, code sample of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Do you use any particular language? Please edit question and use proper tags. What `google-web-designer` is doing here?

Comment: okay sir, i am using C# as a programming language, no sorry google-web-designer has nothing to do here, its tagged by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the calendar object which is present in the toolbox. From that you can select whichever date you want to select and store it in database